Белый IP-адрес при работе одного роутера от другого
Всем доброго времени суток! У меня в доме стоит роутер, к которому я имею доступ, но не могу его настроить. Мне разрешили подключить к основному роутеру свой личный (как доп. устройство).
Какой IP-адрес получит мой личный роутер в таком случае, свой личный или адрес основного роутера? Смогу ли я сделать проброс портов без настроек в основном роутере?

У твоего роутера будет внутренний ip.
Получить доступ из интернета к твоему роутеру не получится, без изменения настроек у роутера с белым ip.
